# Scheduling tasks from Queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a use case where I have a list of items(events) getting generated.

I have to process them at regular intervals (like 30 secs).

I want to use a queue to store the events and have a scheduler to process the entries one by one and push it back again into the queue to process once again.

There are two problems with this approach.

1. Queue is never empty,so scheduler is in an infinite loop.
2. This cannot be scaled across multiple similar processes.

Please help.

I am using Spring boot. They need to proccessed till they are removed programatically.

Comment: Which frameworks are you using? Also when you say that you have to push them back into the queue, how many times do you have to process them again?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: what do u mean by : This cannot be scaled across multiple similar processes.: do u mean multiple servers ?

Comment: Yes. Across multiple servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project can incorporate extra 3rd party tools then I would do as follows:

For queue I'd use `RabbitMq` (with back-up replica) which would solve scaling problems as all your spring-boot applications could easily subscribe to `RabbitMq`.

Speaking of 30 second delay, this can be done in several ways. For instance you can "block" your message for 30 seconds programmatically and then throw it back into the queue where message will be consumed by the next 'random' consumer.

Other option would be to use `RabbitMq` delay plugin. You can read more about this plugin [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/). Essentially the message will be held for X seconds in the exchange before it will get to queue where then it will processed by consumer.

Comment: Thank you. The plugin serves the purpose exactly.

Comment: Nice suggestion